# Divide a list by a single value from another file, for multiple files

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to divide every value from a list by a single value from another data file, but repeatedly for 100+ files.

I import my data as below:

```
DataSet1 = Import[#, {"Data", All, 6}] & /@ MyFiles1;
SingleValue = Import[#, {"Data", 6}] & /@ MyFiles2;
```

An example of what `DataSet1` and `SingleValue` would look like is below:

```
DataSet1 = {{0.00987, 0.12345, 0.06666, 0.04532},{0.02431, 0.07000, 0.13245},{0.01111}}
SingleValue ={{0.123},{0.456},{0.789}}
```

I would like to divide each list imported in `DataSet1` by each single value imported by `SingleValue`, is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do it. Perhaps you could tell us which element you would like to use? Is it based on its position, its value? And perhaps you should consider providing us with two toy model lists. Two small ones, that have the correct dimensions. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I've added some toy lists in, hope that clears it up a little! I'd like to divide each list in the DataSet1, by the corresponding values in SingleValue, if that makes sense?

Comment: You mean you want to divide set 1 in `Dataset1` by first number in `Single` and set 2 in `Dataset1` by the second number and so on?  If so, you can try `DataSet1/Flatten@SingleValue` but may be I misunderstood you.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYU6x.png)

Comment: Also `DataSet1 #&/@(Flatten@SingleValue^-1)`

Answer (score 4):

Please work with symbols in this case till you have a working solution. It is much easier to verify the transformation.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
DataSet1 = {{a, b, c, d}, {g, h, i}, {j}};
SingleValue = {{p}, {q}, {r}};

DataSet1/# & /@ Sequence @@@ SingleValue
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \left\{\frac{a}{p},\frac{b}{p},\frac{c}{p},\frac{d}{p}\right\} & \left\{\frac{g}{p},\frac{h}{p},\frac{i}{p}\right\} & \left\{\frac{j}{p}\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{a}{q},\frac{b}{q},\frac{c}{q},\frac{d}{q}\right\} & \left\{\frac{g}{q},\frac{h}{q},\frac{i}{q}\right\} & \left\{\frac{j}{q}\right\} \\
 \left\{\frac{a}{r},\frac{b}{r},\frac{c}{r},\frac{d}{r}\right\} & \left\{\frac{g}{r},\frac{h}{r},\frac{i}{r}\right\} & \left\{\frac{j}{r}\right\} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to the suggestion by @Syed

```
Flatten[Outer[Times, 1/SingleValue, DataSet1], 1];
% // MatrixForm
```

> [image: res]